# card.io cannot recognize card

Tags: android, card.io

I use card.io sample code at my app, but scanning does not snapping the card, only focused on it. OnActivityResult does not get any data. What can help? Use Asus TF300t.

```
 public void onScanPress() {
    // This method is set up as an onClick handler in the layout xml
    // e.g. android:onClick="onScanPress"

    Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, CardIOActivity.class);

    // customize these values to suit your needs.
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: true
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false); // default: false
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false); // default: false

    // hides the manual entry button
    // if set, developers should provide their own manual entry mechanism in the app
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, false); // default: false

    // matches the theme of your application
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME, true); // default: false

    // MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
    startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and onResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String resultStr;
    if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)) {
        CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);

        // Never log a raw card number. Avoid displaying it, but if necessary use getFormattedCardNumber()
        resultStr = "Card Number: " + scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber() + "\n";

        // Do something with the raw number, e.g.:
        // myService.setCardNumber( scanResult.cardNumber );

        if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {
            resultStr += "Expiration Date: " + scanResult.expiryMonth + "/" + scanResult.expiryYear + "\n";
        }

        if (scanResult.cvv != null) {
            // Never log or display a CVV
            resultStr += "CVV has " + scanResult.cvv.length() + " digits.\n";
        }

        if (scanResult.postalCode != null) {
            resultStr += "Postal Code: " + scanResult.postalCode + "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        resultStr = "Scan was canceled.";
    }
   // resultTextView.setText(resultStr);

}
```

I use 4.0.0 aar, and I does not provide jniLibs (they must be at .aar, I suppose)

Comment: Я думаю это не проблема в твоем коде. Эта библиотека использует специфические алгоритмы обнаружения и ты должен держать устройство в определеннмо положении что бы она смогла распознать каточку. Она не всегда распознает карточку, нужен яркий свет, отчетливый номер на карточке и устройство с хорошей камерой. Как только камера сфокусируется на карточку по сторонам начнут загораются зеленым толстые линии. Основная задача юзера - что бы все стороны были выделены зеленым.

Comment: @Govtart у меня все стороны выделяет зеленым и затеняет задний фон. Но дальнейшей реакции нет, onResultActivity не вызывается.

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult will only be called if the card was recognized, user entered a card manually or user cancelled. as @Govtart explained not all cards can be recognized. Make sure to try [Sample app](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp) first